# Regex - exclude search results

Tags: regex

I am looking for my changes in log file.
Here is example:

```
"2-11-2016 11:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class1 Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
"2-11-2016 12:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class2 Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
"2-11-2016 13:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class2 Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
"2-11-2016 14:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class1 Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
"2-11-2016 15:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class3 Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
...
"2-11-2016 15:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed FirstClass Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
"2-11-2016 15:39:27 CET","somemail@gmail.com","Changed SecondClass Apex Class code","Apex Class",""
```

I already know that I changed Class1 and Class2. So I need to find another classes that I changed (SecondClass in this example)

**how to create regex to exclude Class1 and Class2?**
I use search in Sublime Text

Comment: SublimeText2 or 3? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did you down vote my question?

Comment: I haven't. I can even prove it by upvoting, but seriously, there is nothing to upvote it for. First, it is unclear. Second, you provided no effort (again, we do not know what you tried and what you want to get, attempts usually clarify what you are doing). Third, you did not tag the question with the tool you are using.

Comment: Try `Class[^12]`. It will match Class*, except Class1 & Class2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please check what I have updated

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In essence I want to know all classes what I have changed. So easiest way I imagine - to take first one and exclude it, and find next. And go to the last changed class by excluding all previously found search results. Example: find class1, exclude it to find class2, exclude class3 to find FirstClass etc...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes this is what I need. Can you put it to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you need to match some string that is not followed with a number (that you are going to add manually after each match) as a *whole word*.

You may use a negative lookahead based regex with a group of alternatives `(...|...|etc.)` and a word boundary `\b`:

```
"somemail@gmail.com","Changed Class(?!(123|12|1|2|3)\b)
|
---------- a known part --------------------|negative lookahead|
```

The negative lookahead fails the match if the known part is followed with `123`, or `12`, etc. followed with a word boundary (see `(123|12|1|2|3)\b`). The capturing group can be replaced with a non-capturing one that is only  used for grouping: `(123|12|1|2|3)` => `(?:123|12|1|2|3)` (meaning it won't put any subtext into `$1`, Group 1).